# android error IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I can't find following error in my code. It looks like the problem is in the asynctask onpostexecute.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:672)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:368)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:160)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:319)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:302)
at www.mobilezar.mn.Advertisements$InitialLoading.onPostExecute(Advertisements.java:216)
at www.mobilezar.mn.Advertisements$InitialLoading.onPostExecute(Advertisements.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post code that is causing this error?

Comment: This error is coming up at line no 216 of Advertisements.java can you show what are you doing at this line